# How to fix 'Error in getter for watcher "isDark"' in Vue

Tags: vue.js

Some time ago I developed a form with Vue, importing Vuetify as a library so to speak, despite some warnings the form worked perfectly, it stopped working showing the following error

```
"Error in getter for watcher" isDark ":" TypeError: this. $ vuetify.theme is undefined "
```

I do not know if it is due to a change of version of Vue, I already gave several turns to the problem and I find no solution

This is what I mean as I implemented vue and vuetify

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, if you are getting "TypeError: this. $ vuetify.theme is undefined" when trying to move from 1.5 to 2.0, it's like to be a case of not following the upgrade guide correctly.

See the bootstrap bit of https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases#user-content-upgrade-guide. There are some subtle changes in the examples e.g. passing 'vuetify' to new Vue. Not following that bit of the upgrade guide can generate the above error.

Comment: That link is not going to the proper location.

Comment: This is the correct link: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/releases-and-migrations/#migration-guide